# Telerik ASP.NET Grid Column Template Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

**I want to put a link in my Telerik grid that will call an Edit action in my Contact controller. The code that I have puts the link in its respective place but gives me a 400 Bad Request Error. I have a feeling that there is a problem with the syntax behind my columns.Template code.**

*Here is the Index view*

```
columns.Template(
       @<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContactId })
       </text>
      ).ClientTemplate(@"<a href=""/Contact/Edit?id=<#= ContactId #>"">View</a>");
```

**Here is the ContactController**

```
// GET: Client/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            using (var provosity = new ProvosityContext())
            {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Contact contact = provosity.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(contact);
            }
        }

        // POST: Client/Edit/5
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var provosity = new ProvosityContext())
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                provosity.Entry(contact).State=System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                provosity.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

                return View(contact);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }

        }



}
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I had to change:

Comment: To:

).ClientTemplate(@"<a href=""/Contact/Edit?id=#= ContactId #"">View</a>");

Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here goes like i do:

```
c.Bound(p => p.ContactId).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Edit", "Controller Name") + "/#= ContactId #'" + ">View</a>");
```